# H2 embedded database not initialized when using Spring's lazy initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, spring-jdbc

I have an application that successfully uses an embedded H2 database in tests (Spring Boot v2.7.18, H2 v2.2.220).
Problem is, that if I add the `spring.main.lazy-initialization = true` property to try to speed up tests, the initialization .sql script I give to H2 isn't used anymore.
Here's how H2 is set up:

```yaml
spring:
  #main:
  #  lazy-initialization: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    type: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
  sql:
    init:
      mode: embedded
      data-locations:
        - classpath:test-schema.sql
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: false
```

The .sql script that isn't used with lazy initialization is `test-schema.sql`.
"Boilerplate" test data is added to the database before every test from another .sql file via the following annotation put on the test class:
`@Sql(scripts = {"classpath:test-data.sql"}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)`
The script starts off with a series of `DELETE FROM <table>` to clean the database and then does all the needed `INSERT INTO <table> ...` commands.

The specific error I get when trying to run queries on the database is `Table "MyTable" not found (this database is empty)`.

```
 WARN  2024-02-19 15:57:16,838 [Test worker] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager - Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@456abb66] for test method [public void com.example.myapp.MyTests.myTest()] and test instance [com.example.myapp.MyTests@4718d320]
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [test-data.sql]: DELETE FROM MyTable; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MyTable" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
DELETE FROM MyTable [42104-214]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$4(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MyTable" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
DELETE FROM MyTable [42104-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSimpleTableFilter(Parser.java:1160)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseDelete(Parser.java:1174)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:774)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261)
    ... 83 more
```

Things that I've tried:

- Adding `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true` to the YAML
- Adding `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` to the datasource url
- Adding the following static bean trying to exclude from lazy initialization several of the database-related beans and auto-configurations that I found:

```java
@Bean
public static LazyInitializationExcludeFilter integrationLazyInitializationExcludeFilter() {
    return LazyInitializationExcludeFilter.forBeanTypes(DataSource.class, 
            H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class, EmbeddedDataSourceConfiguration.class, 
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DatabasePopulator.class, 
            DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class, 
            DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.class, 
            JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class);
}
```

Nothing worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not really possible to reproduce the error you see with given information.
1. How do you initialize your schema?, 2. what is inside test-schema.sql?
3. What is the full stacktrace?

Comment: I don't manually initialize it, all I need (when not using lazy initialization) are these YAML settings I wrote in the question: `sql.init.mode: embedded` and `sql.init.data-locations: - classpath:test-schema.sql`. the `DataSource` bean is autowired via a "required args" constructor in the @Service class that uses it, I don't manually declare a DataSource bean or do any additional configurations on it. test-schema.sql contains a series of "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ..." at the beginning, followed by all the needed "CREATE TABLE ..." commands. I'll update the question with the full error stacktrace.

Comment: The problem is that the initializing is done with a `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` which is an `InitializingBean`. Normally this will be kicked of eagerly but due to the `spring.main.lazy-initialization = true` this will not happen. Nor will it be triggered by the creation of a `DataSource` and hence will never run. So what you probably should excluce, which looks like is missing, is the `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` and/or the `SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration`. That should simply trigger the `DataSource` creation so much more shouldn't be needed in the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but still can't reproduce your problem.
1. Initialised a springboot project with h2 following your version
2. added test-schema.sql(create a simple table), test-data.sql(delete from the simple table)and application.yml follow what you provided.
3. added a springboot test with `@Sql` suggested.
4. no error shown when running the test, no matter having `spring.main.lazy-initialization = true` or not.

Comment: Thank you so muuuuch, adding `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` to that static bean works! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. I don't know why you can't reproduce the issue. I do have other annotations on the test class but I thought they had nothing to do with the issue... who knows. I'm happy with this solution anyway.

Comment: To be precise, `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.class` alone in that static bean solves my issue. I don't need to exclude anything else from lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the initializing is done with a `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` which is an `InitializingBean`. Normally this will be kicked of eagerly but due to the `spring.main.lazy-initialization = true` this will not happen. Nor will it be triggered by the creation of a `DataSource` and hence will never run.

So what you probably should exclude, which looks like is missing, is the `SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` and/or the `SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration`. That should simply trigger the `DataSource` creation so much more shouldn't be needed in the filter.

```java
@Bean
public static LazyInitializationExcludeFilter integrationLazyInitializationExcludeFilter() {
    return LazyInitializationExcludeFilter.forBeanTypes(SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.class);
}
```

Something like this.